# How to fix "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session" error when using one-to-one relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create a one-to-one relationship between 2 entities:

- Project entity

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "projects")
  public class Project {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      private CrawlerConfiguration crawlerConfiguration;

      // Getters and setters ...

      public void setCrawlerConfiguration(CrawlerConfiguration crawlerConfiguration) {
          if (crawlerConfiguration == null) {
              if (this.crawlerConfiguration != null) {
                  this.crawlerConfiguration.setProject(null);
              }
          } else {
              crawlerConfiguration.setProject(this);
          }

          this.crawlerConfiguration = crawlerConfiguration;
      }
  ```
- CrawlerConfiguration entity

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "crawler_configurations")
  public class CrawlerConfiguration {

      @Id
      private Long id;

      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @MapsId
      private Project project;

      // Getters and setters ...
  }
  ```

When the user creates a new project, a configuration should also be created for the project.

```
@Transactional
public Project createProject(Project project) {
    project.setCrawlerConfiguration(new CrawlerConfiguration());
    return projectRepository.save(project);
}
```

Unfortunately it results in the following exception:

> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session :
>   [com.github.peterbencze.serritorcloud.model.entity.CrawlerConfiguration#1]

What is the correct way to create the entities?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
 private Project project;
```

In your CrawlerConfiguration entity

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried adding PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation and it resulted in a different exception: `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.github.peterbencze.serritorcloud.model.entity.CrawlerConfiguration`

Comment: Sorry missed that. Your crawler_configurations table has an Id column? You should also add     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) on Id of CrawlerConfiguration entity   and maybe add also @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)

Comment: After adding both annotations, it no longer throws exception. However, it generates 2 rows in the database for the configuration.

Comment: SELECT * FROM CRAWLER_CONFIGURATIONS;

`ID  
1
2`